# Pass Seralizer URL params

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework

**some context:**

I am trying to determine which DB to use (every user has its own db) by a given url param.

**When url is** `"domain/<identifier>/Guest/"`

identifier is the url_param i need to pass to the serializer to use that DB

I understand i need to override the `create(self,validated_data)` from the serializer

**serializer.py**

```
class GuestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        db="???"
        return models.Guest.objects.using(db).create(**validated_data)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Guest
        fields = "__all__"
```

So i need to pass the url param information to the serializer

I'd like to know if there is a better approach

**Update to anyone in my situation**

this solves the issue

```
db = self.context['request'].parser_context['kwargs']['identifier']
```

Comment: So `db` should be `identifier` from the URL path?

Comment: yes,  that is its purpose